# How can I reference C# objects in GDScript (and vice versa)?

Tags: c#, godot, mono

I am using Godot Engine 3.0.6 Mono for Windows x64.
I am prototyping the majority of my project in C# before I rewrite the game in C++ for release. I installed [this plugin](https://github.com/QuentinCaffeino/godot-console) mostly to help with testing and debugging value-sensitive functionality. To make this possible however, I will need to be able to make references to my C# classes from GDScript (or vice versa) for binding commands. I could not find any instructions on how to do this in the official documentation.
Can this be done currently in either direction?

*Note: If the references are made from C# to GDScript classes, I need to be able to cast the Nodes respectively to make function calls.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how this works both ways after a couple of days.

It is not immediately obvious and the GDScript interpreter will yell at you, but as long as your C# objects are included in the .csproj file and the class itself extends Object, you can call any method in the C# script.

The C# API adds a nice way of calling GDScript instance functions, which is are the Godot.Object methods `Call()`, `CallDeferred()`, and `Callv()`.

E.G. given:

### SampleGD.gd

```
func from_csharp(content):
    print(content)
```

Then in C# you would obtain a reference to this object in the scene or use `ResourceLoader` to load a new instance. After such, you could do:

### SampleCS.cs

```
var sampleGD = FindNode("SampleGD");
sampleGD.Call("from_csharp", "Hello from C#!");
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find an example of the reverse, SampleGD calling a (new) method of SampleCS. Would you be kind enough to show us an example of bi-directional calling between gdscript and csharp?

Comment: the problem i had was due to operator overloading meaning there was no valid csharp function for the arguments called from gdscript. the type of gdscript arguments likely needs to be specified as `GodotObject`. `public partial class mycsharp : Node2D { public void mymethod(GodotObject arg1){GD.Print("mycsharp:mymethod:arg1=", arg1)}}` and gdscript `func _ready(): $mycsharp.mymethod(self)` seemed to work in one manual test case